# Is there a property in javascript Object.type?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I am studying Node.Js right now and came across this piece of code:

```
  var combine = require('stream-combiner');
  var through = require('through2');
  var split = require('split');
  var zlib = require('zlib');

  module.exports = function () {
      var grouper = through(write, end);
      var current;

      function write (line, _, next) {
          if (line.length === 0) return next();
          var row = JSON.parse(line);

          if (row.type === 'genre') {
             if (current) {
                 this.push(JSON.stringify(current) + '\n');
             }
              current = { name: row.name, books: [] };
          }
          else if (row.type === 'book') {
              current.books.push(row.name);
          }
          next();
      }
      function end (next) {
          if (current) {
              this.push(JSON.stringify(current) + '\n');
          }
          next();
      }

      return combine(split(), grouper, zlib.createGzip());
  };
```

Each line the write function gets is a json line that looks like this:

```
"name": "Neuromancer","genre": "cyberpunk"
```

And the expected outcome is the following JSON object:

```
{
"name": "cyberpunk",
"books": [
  "Accelerando",
  "Snow Crash",
  "Neuromancer",
  "The Diamond Age",
  "Heavy Weather"
]}
```

and etc.

Basically my question is - what does the row.type means?

Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: It's a property within the JSON parameter `line`.  It could be anything - no way to tell from this

Comment: Where did you find that code? Are you sure it actually works? The JSON sample has no `type` property, so `row.type` would always be `undefined` if that's really what the input looks like.

Comment: Exactly my thought. It is part of a WorkShop I am using to study Node.JS so I guess they know what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You put the **type** parameter in the var **row** doing

```
var row = JSON.parse(line);
```

so that's not a special property o function of the object, it's only, simply, a parameter that was in the JSON (of var **line**)

Comment: Okey.
So basically I somehow added type property to the JSON by doing JSON.parse()?